# How to manually check whether json web token is valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to determine whether JWT Token is valid in `[AllowAnonymouse]]` endpoint

## edit

> I have an endpoint which can be accessed by anyone (authorized and unauthorized people) and then: If that user has http authorization header OR he has token in cookies and his token valid then redirect him to X otherwise to Y

Pseudocode of my idea:

```
[Route("Passport/")]
public IActionResult Passport()
{
    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    or pseudocode:
    if (tokenIsValid(getJWTTokenFromHeader()));
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Resources");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

I thought about something like this:

```
[Route("Passport/")]
public IActionResult Passport()
{
    var token = ExtractTokenFromHeader();
    
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue
    ("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    
    var get = client.GetAsync($"http://localhost/verifyToken").Result;

    var responseBody = await get.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    switch (get.StatusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
            return RedirectToAction("Resources");
        default:
            return RedirectToAction(...);
    }
}
```

Where endpoint verifyToken has an `[Authorize]` attribute and just returns Unauthorized (defaultly) or OK (from code)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, your question is not clear

Comment: I have an endpoint which can be accessed by anyone (authorized and unauthorized people) and then: If that user has http authorization header OR he has token in cookies and his token valid then redirect him to X otherwise to Y

Comment: Use a policy instead of checking the token in your controller method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @aguafrommars sounds great, but I still have to determine whether token is valid in ``HandleRequirement``?

Comment: So what's wrong with just using `if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin for some reason it was always false even when jwt was OK and other [Authorize] endpoint let me go thru with that token.

Answer (score -1):

You may try below code

```
private static bool ValidateJWTToken(string token, out string username) {  
    username = null;  
    var simplePrinciple = JwtManager.GetPrincipal(token);  
    var identity = simplePrinciple.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;  
    if (identity == null) return false;  
    if (!identity.IsAuthenticated) return false; 
}
```